# How do I connect 2 networks in different data centers openstack ovh horizon

Tags: openstack, datacenter, ovh, openstack-horizon

I have an OpenStack project with my cloud infrastructure. Now, I need to separate one instance from this project and move it into another project, but it still has to be reachable from my network in Project A. Initially, I achieved this by creating a network in Project B within the same vRACK, using the same vlanID, and sharing it with Project A, which worked successfully.

However, my current challenge is transferring this instance from Project B to another Datacenter. After doing so, it becomes invisible.

Could you please assist me with this issue?

Thanks and regards. ^^

Comment: Use a VLAN or global IP addresses. If applicable, you could also use a direct connection between your both data centers.